# Does Android send crash reports (in Google Play) for NDK/C++ crahses?

Tags: android, android-ndk

My impression is that crashes in NDK side does not open "Report crash" view for the users, application is just silently killed. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Android is not Windows ...

Comment: I think that is correct, when I was debugging crashing native code, it will only pause in debugger, no UI informing user to send feedback like Java crashes. I don't see any C++ native error reported in my Google Play console either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stock NDK does not but Google breakpad has a [custom reporter for native Android](http://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/source/browse/trunk/README.ANDROID) code that might help.